# Formatting shortcuts with sublime text 2

Tags: html, formatting, sublimetext2

This question is asked more out of curiosity than necessity, but does anyone know of a way to auto-format a block of code in Sublime Text 2?

When I add a new block of code I have to click enter a couple times, jump up a line or two, then press TAB to get to the point where I can continue typing code in between  tags for example.

Is it possible to achieve the following format with one or two keystrokes?

```
<div>
     <p> Some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a Sublime Text plugin called [Emmet](http://emmet.io)

It allows to write code blocks super quick. Once the plugin is installed you simply write your code in the following format: `.container>.row>.col-lg-4*3>p`.
Then hit TAB and you will get the following output:

`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Saves me loads of time and there are some good Youtube tutorials on how to make use of all of its features.